# I can't actually use my Ubuntu install right now. It's a read only file system

Tags: fsck, read-only

I was doing a system restart after updates, and I had a momentary loss of power to my machine, and now it's a read-only file system on my Ubuntu install.  I tried to startx, but that won't work when it's in "rescue mode" apparently. Even booting off of a live media, and trying to run fsck on the HDD where the install is does not work.  I get this error message:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sde is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

But the thing is, it's not even mounted, so I can't be using it.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Commenting in lieu of someone more knowledgeable: maybe try running fsck from a live disc?

Answer (score 0):

In rescue mode, rescue mode mounts in read only. You need to choose the option "fix broken packages" or remount using the following command to mount in read write mode:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

NEVER try to do `startx` when running as root! This can mess up your file permissions for your xauthority file!